# debian and owncloud accessible by name in LAN?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, debian

I would like to set up a debian machine with an owncloud.

I would like to achieve, that the machine is reachable by webbrowser just by entering an address, not an IP address. - in LAN only.

So I do not need a dyndns, as it provides the Internet IP address.
I do not have access to the router either, IP is set to static, but is outside of DHCP range.
The machine will be used in different locations, so the IP Adress might change.

How can I achieve this, with only access to the debian machine?

Comment: I'm 99% sure davs://[hostname]/owncloud/ should do it just fine, but I'm not an OC user.

Comment: Just tried, but does not work. However, its not related to OC. It could reach simply the apache on it.

Comment: I run an internal Bind server (for a small zone, its not that rough) to resolve internal names, and use Forwarders to send unresolvable queries up to Internet DNS servers to resolve external queries. Just set up Bind on your Deb server, configure your zone and forwarders, and point your clients to it, perhaps by pushing the DNS server address via DHCP. or if thats too complicated for you, just create a custom host file for your lan and manually deploy it to your clients.

Comment: The client systems wanting to connect to the server will need some way of finding the IP address from the name. Browsers will do this either via DNS or a lookup in the local `hosts` file. If you have only access to the server, you won't be able to solve this.